# How to change combobox selection list applied to a table cell

Tags: javafx, combobox, tablecolumn

I have a table column with combobox as its cell factory. The value in this combobox depicts the no. of rows in the table. So as I add any new row to the table, the list set in the combobox increases as shown.

```
ObservableList<Integer> sequenceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
sequenceList.add(1);
btnAdd.setOnAction((e) -> {
            sequenceList.add(counter);
            fileTable.getItems().add(new InstallationPack("enter file name", "--select--", "extensions", counter));
            counter++;
        });
```

here sequenceList is the list applied to the combobox.

The table column cell factory is as shown

```
tbFileColSeq.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<InstallationPack, Integer>, TableCell<InstallationPack, Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<InstallationPack, Integer> call(TableColumn<InstallationPack, Integer> param) {
                return new ComboBoxCellFactory<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(seq));
            }

        });
```

Here ComboBoxCellFactory is a class applying combobox to the table column as graphic.
My problem is that the column's cell factory is called for all its row (whether empty or not) in the beginning itself while declaring. So the list passed in the table cell combobox is old. i.e the original one and not the latest one.
So when I add a new row it shows me the old list.

Can anyone suggest anyway in which this combobox list can be updated?

EDIT:Given below is the code of ComboBoxCellFactory class

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;

public class ComboBoxCellFactory<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    private final ComboBox<T> comboBox;

    public ComboBoxCellFactory(ObservableList<T> items) {
        this.comboBox = new ComboBox<>(items);
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox) getGraphic();
        comboBox.setId("comboBoxTableCell");
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        comboBox.setOnShown(new EventHandler<Event>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(getIndex());

            }
        });

        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<T>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> obs, T oldValue, T newValue) {

                commitEdit(newValue);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {

    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
//                System.out.println(item);
            comboBox.setValue(item);
            setGraphic(comboBox);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ComboBoxCellFactory`? Can't you just do `tbFileColSeq.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(sequenceList));`?

Comment: As I already mentioned, ComboBoxCellFactory is a separate class I'm refferring for applying the combobox view to the column. I'm making a separate class so that my table goes into edit mode in 1 click. But that is not the issue, Even if I replace my code with the one you mentioned, the cellFactory will be called initially for all the rows. So the combobox value going in the cell won't get refreshed.

Comment: If you use the standard `ComboBoxTableCell` and pass it an `ObservableList`, that observable list will be used by all the combo boxes that the factory creates. So if you then change *that list*, the content of the combo boxes will changes accordingly. (I just tested this.) In your code, you create a *new list* with `FXCollections.observableArrayList(...)` and pass it to your factory. I don't know if it will behave the same way if you pass it the actual list you are modifying, because you haven't shown the code for your factory, but that is how you would do it with the standard class.

Comment: @James_D Your solution is working. Thanks. But I avoided this because  on double click it shows me the combobox and take the cell in editing mode. So I wrote ComboBoxCellFactory class to view the combobox without any click and takes the cell in editing mode on 1 click. Can you suggest any change I can make here So that my comboxbox list gets updated using my method. I have edited my question and added the code of ComboBoxCellFactory class.

Comment: Just make the same change. Pass the list you are actually modifying instead of a new list. I.e. `return new ComboBoxCellFactory<>(sequenceList);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new observable list and passing it to your `ComboBoxCellFactory` (which is really a cell, not a cell factory):

```
return new ComboBoxCellFactory<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(seq));
```

Because `FXCollections.observableArrayList(...)` creates a *new* list, the combo boxes are not referencing the same list you are modifying. Therefore they are not aware of any changes to that list.

Instead, pass the actual list to which you are making the changes. E.g., assuming you are adding elements to `seq` (whatever that is), you would do

```
return new ComboBoxCellFactory<>(seq);
```

Comment: It works exactly as I want it to... Thank you so much. :)